# How to increase the speed of audio in CMSampleBuffer

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, cmsamplebuffer, cmsamplebufferref

What is the process to speed up audio recieved via CMSampleBuffer so that is recorded at 2X speed.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?